# How can I extend the lock screen timeout in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, screen-lock

This question is applicable to both iPads and iPhones: how do I extend the lock screen timeout? By that I mean the time from when I see the "slide to unlock" message to when the screen goes black again. Right now when I press a button to wake my device up, I have about four or five seconds to slide the screen to unlock, before it just goes dark again. I would like to extend this timeout if possible. How do I do it?

Comment: The possible solution would be to jailbreak the iPad's and iPhones if you need to customize according to your will.

Comment: @JashJacob Not a solution. Apple needs to address this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without jailbreaking your iPhone there Is no option to change that.

Comment: I've been dealing with this issue since the low power mode came out. I now hate apple.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you need to know (I think) : First, the OP is about whether it’s possible to extend the amount of time the lock screen stays lit, not how long it takes before the unlocked device’s lock screen kicks in.

In doing some experimentation with an IPhone 6 and IPad Pro (2nd gen) both using iOS 12.4, Apple has set 2 timers for the lock screen and 1 timer for the widget screen (accessed by swiping to the right). **None of the timers are adjustable in Settings**

*Without* a notification present, the **main lock screen** will remain lit for 5 seconds before going black. *With* a notification present, the lock screen remains lit for 10 seconds before going black.

The **Widget screen** will stay lit for 10 seconds before dimming and then 5 seconds later will go black.

Things you CAN’T do to keep the lock screen lit:

- use the **sleep/lock button**. This does nothing but turn off the lock screen prematurely. Once the lock screen goes black, pressing it again will bring back the lock screen and reset the 5 or 10 second timer. As suggested in other posts, there doesn’t appear to be any tricks to use the sleep/lock button to increase the length of the timer.
- Pressing the **Home button**. Pressing it brings up the login screen. Once the lock screen goes black, pressing it will bring back the lock screen and reset the 5 or 10 second timer.

Things you CAN do to keep the lock screen lit:

- pressing one of the volume buttons (up or down) every 3-4 seconds will reset the timer and keep the login screen lit.
- keeping a finger on the screen *within the notification display area* (near or on the actual notifications) AND moving the screen slightly up and down or physically sliding your finger side-to-side every few seconds will keep the screen lit.
- keeping a finger on the screen near the left or right edges of the lighted screen AND moving the screen slightly side-to-side every few seconds will keep the screen lit. Physically moving your finger up and down or **tapping the screen** in this area will not work.

**Bottom line** : the best solutions to keep the screen lit in order to read notifications appear to be to press the volume buttons or use a finger near the left or right edge of the screen as described above. For me personally, placing my right thumb in the bottom right part of the screen and slightly moving the screen side-to-side keeps the screen lit while I use my left thumb to scroll through the notifications.

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 1):

I have accidentally found that pushing the on/off button exactly as the lock screen is dimming will keep the lock screen lit. No idea how long it stays on but doing this does prolong lock screen. It lasts at least 6 minutes and possibly forever. I am on iPhone 7. No idea how to set a timer for it though.

Answer (score 1):

Could not find Auto-Lock, search box took me to Display & Brightness and it's there.  You can set to 2, 5, 10,or 15 minutes, or Never.

Comment: +1 Not exactly what the OP asked about, but this is where I landed after googling iphone lock screen timeout, and this did the trick

Answer (score 0):

For those still searching for a workaround for this, you can also slide the display up or down with your finger to extend the display.  That is, after you "wake" the device and see your notifications, put your index finger on the display and slide it up (or down).  Each minimal "scroll" of the screen resets the countdown timer back to 5 seconds, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I know of two ways (I use iPhone 6s plus):

1. Once you are in the locked screen you may press the volume button in intervals of few seconds as long as you want the screen to remain on.
2. You may alternatively slide to get your widget screen (that is on the left, right side is camera). You need to remove all items from the widget first. This will not stop the timeout but it will do two things differently. First, it doubles the timeout interval from 5 to 10 seconds and second, after 10 seconds the screen goes dimmer instead of abruptly locking it which gives you time to react.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got 4 iPads locked in a case without access to the on off and home button. The iPad are connected to power. It’s impossible to keep the 4 iPad from locking within this 2-sec period. But, when the iPads are actually turned of (assistive touch-lock-slide) and then turn the external power back on the iPads starts up and stays in the Home Screen without locking after 2 seconds (old iPad Air on iOS 12).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/344800)

Answer (score -1):

iOS 8
Settings > General > Auto Lock

Comment: This is nothing to do with the lock screen timeout.

Answer (score -1):

Pressing the on/off button as the screen begins to dim is indeed the solution to this "irritation," as first suggested by Wdtony. I just got the iPhone 7 Plus, on which the lock screen dims about two seconds faster than on my iPhone 5, by my "one-one-thousand" reckoning. This also works for the iPhone 5, so presumedly, it also works for the "6" line of iPhones.

Answer (score -2):

You can only do it after jail breaking else it's not possible.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score -4):

iOS settings > general > Battery > low power mode > off

iOS settings > general > Auto lock

Comment: This is nothing to do with the lock screen timeout.